# React update child state from parent component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

I have a parent component as follow:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';
import GridItem from './gridItem.js'

class Grid extends Component {
  renderGridItems = () => {
    const gridItems = this.props.gridItems,
          itemsHTML = [];

    for(let i = 1; i < (gridItems + 1); i++){
        itemsHTML.push(
          <GridItem hidden={false} key={i}>{i}</GridItem>
        )
    }

    return itemsHTML
  }
  hideGridItem() {
      console.log('hide single grid item')
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="grid">
        {this.renderGridItems()}
        <button onClick={this.hideGridItem()}>hide random grid item</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

Grid.propTypes = {
    renderGridItems: PropTypes.func,
    gridItems: PropTypes.number
}

export default Grid;
```

and a child one:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

class GridItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        hidden: false
    }
  }
  hideGridItem = () => {
    this.setState({ hidden: true })
  }
  render() {
    const hideGridItem = this.state.hidden ? " hide": ""

    return (
      <div className={"gird-item" + hideGridItem}>
        {this.props.children}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default GridItem;
```

Inside the "Grid" component, I would like to randomly (only for now) pick a single "gridItem" to set its "hidden" prop to true onClick.

Comment: can you provide griditems data

Comment: In `constructor` you can initiate state from props : `hidden: props.hidden`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You aren't using the parent provided `hidden` prop in the child item:

```
const hideGridItem = this.state.hidden ? " hide": ""
```

Should be:

```
const hideGridItem = this.props.hidden ? " hide": ""
```

State should be internal to the component, and not modified directly from other components. But you probably meant props anyway.

With that prop, you could do something like this, in the parent:

```
hideGridItem() {
  index = Math.floor(Math.random() * this.props.gridItems.length);
  this.setState({hiddenIndex: index});
}
```

And then in the render method:

```
for(let i = 1; i < gridItems.length; i++) {
  itemsHTML.push(
    <GridItem hidden={this.state.hiddenIndex === i} key={i}>{i}</GridItem>);
}
```

Not sure the expression `(GridItems + 1)` in the for loop is doing what you want. Also, you [should not be using the index as a key](https://medium.com/@robinpokorny/index-as-a-key-is-an-anti-pattern-e0349aece318).

Answer (score 1):

Set hidden based on a random selection of the grid indices

```
// may not be the best way to get a random GridItem index
const hidden_i = (Math.floor(Math.random() * gridItems) + 1
for(let i = 1; i < (gridItems + 1); i++){
    itemsHTML.push(
      <GridItem hidden={i == hidden_i} key={i}>{i}</GridItem>
    )
}
```

Comment: Your `hidden_i` will never be index 0, and may be > the number of items. Remove the + 1. What does `(gridItems + 1)`, or an array times a number, evaluate to?

Comment: @Nick I'm just following his example code - `i` starts at 1, so it never needs to be 0.

Answer (score 1):

Okay I see a place where you are going wrong.

If you have a grid item component and you want to be able to display it and take it off display than do something like this.

```
this.state= { 
 griditems: [{
 hidden:false,
 description:'first grid item',
 id:1
},
{
 hidden:false,
 description:'second grid item',
 id:2
}, ]
}
```

Now when you make your griditems like this in your top level component it will be easier to determine which grid items we want to show or hide.

In your Grid component the following should change

```
renderGridItems () => {
 const { griditems } = this.props 
 return griditems.map(item => !item.hidden ? <div> {item.id} {item.description} <button onClick={this.hideGridItem(item.id)}> HIDE ME</button> </div> : <div onClick={this.show(item.id)}> show </div>
}
```

Now in your hideGridItem.

```
hideGridItem(id) => {
 const { griditems } = this.props
 const currentItem = griditems.filter(item => item.id === id);
 currentItem.hidden = true;
 const newitems = griditems.filter(item => item.id !== id)
 newitems.push(currentItem);
 //now call the setter in your parent component which I made below
 this.props.setGridItems(newitems);
}
```

Now make a showGridItem

```
showGridItem = (id) => {
const { griditems } = this.props
     const currentItem = griditems.filter(item => item.id === id);
     currentItem.hidden = false;
     const newitems = griditems.filter(item => item.id !== id)
     newitems.push(currentItem);
     //now call the setter in your parent component 
     this.props.setGridItems(newitems);
}
```

Back in the parent we will make setGridItems

```
setGridItem (updateditems) => {
 this.setState({ griditems:updateditems });
}
```